# Los enlaces con target _blank dejaron de funcionar en worpdress y elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

en el menu del siteweb realizo lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de ingresar a esta pestaña , esta deberia abrir en una nueva ventana y no lo hace , lo abre en la misma ventana , inspeccione el codigo y me arroja esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el target lo arroja vacio y este deberia llevar la etiqueta _blank

porfavor necesito una ayuda

Answer (score 0):

¿Has comprobado si es un problema de actualizaciones en WordPress, el tema del sitio o el plugin de Elementor?

Intentaría realizar los siguientes pasos:

1. Realizar una copia de seguridad del estado actual del sitio.
2. Actualizar todos los plugins del sitio uno por uno si lo requieren.
3. Actualizar el tema del sitio si lo requiere.
4. Actualizar la versión de WordPress si lo requiere.